# Cannot see finished job in Spark web UI

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using `./bin/spark-submit` to run my Spark job. It runs fine but opening Spark web UI, I cannot see job in completed list.

```
./bin/spark-submit --name "myapp" --master local --conf "spark.master=spark://fahad:7077" --class com.apptest.App ~/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Note: Spark version 2.0.1, 1 worker running, master UI at `localhost:8080` both worker and master ran from `./sbin/start-*.sh` scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different UI's, the regular Spark UI, and the Spark History Server.

The one that shows jobs after they complete is the history server.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

They explain in the docs that you need to start it by running:

```
./sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

> This creates a web interface at http://server-url:18080 by default,
>   listing incomplete and completed applications and attempts.
>
> When using the file-system provider class (see spark.history.provider
>   below), the base logging directory must be supplied in the
>   spark.history.fs.logDirectory configuration option, and should contain
>   sub-directories that each represents an application’s event logs.
>
> The spark jobs themselves must be configured to log events, and to log
>   them to the same shared, writeable directory. For example, if the
>   server was configured with a log directory of
>   hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs, then the client-side options would
>   be:
>
> spark.eventLog.enabled true spark.eventLog.dir
>   hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs