# How to get execution DAG from spark web UI after job has finished running, when I am running spark on YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I frequently do analysis of the DAG of my spark job while it is running.  But, it is annoying to have to sit and watch the application while it is running in order to see the DAG.

So, I tried to view the DAg using this thing called the `spark history-server`, which I know should help me see past jobs.  I'm easily able to access port `18080`, and I can see the history server UI.

But, it doesn't show me any information related to the spark program's execution.  I know I have the history server running, because when I do `sudo service --status-all` I see

`spark history-server is running            [ OK ]`

So I already tried what this question suggested: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936593/cannot-see-finished-job-in-spark-web-ui).

I think this is because I'm running spark on YARN, and it can only use one resource manager at a time? maybe?

So, how do I see the spark execution DAG,  **after** a job has finished?  and more specifically, when running YARN as my resource manager?

Answer (score 3):

Running only `history-server` is not sufficient to get execution `DAG` of previous jobs. You need specify the jobs to store the events logs of all previous jobs.

Run Spark history server by `./sbin/start-history-server.sh`

Enable event log for the spark job

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir <path to event log(local or hdfs)>
spark.history.fs.logDirectory  <path to event log(local or hdfs)>
```

Add these on `spark-defaults.conf` file

Comment: So, I tried starting the history server as you suggested `./sbin/start-history-server.sh`, but I get "command not found".  But, how is this different from starting the history server via `sudo service spark-history-server start`, like in my question?   (also I actually already have those two settings for the `spark.eventLog*` already set in my config).

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: does it matter where exactly I store the logs?  does it matter exactly what is the path for `spark.eventLog.dir`?

Comment: In default it creates file:///tmp/spark-events for logs.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [Monitoring and Instrumentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html), we need following three parameters to be set in `spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.eventLog.enabled
spark.eventLog.dir
spark.history.fs.logDirectory
```

The first property should be `true`

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
```

The second and the third properties should point to the `event-log` locations which can either be `local-file-system` or `hdfs-file-system`. **The second property defines where to store the logs for spark jobs and the third property is for history-server to display logs** in web UI at 18080.

If you choose `linux local-file-system (/opt/spark/spark-events)`
Either

```
spark.eventLog.dir               file:/opt/spark/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    file:/opt/spark/spark-events
```

Or

```
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///opt/spark/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    file:///opt/spark/spark-events
```

should work

If you choose `hdfs-file-system (/spark-events)`
Either

```
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs:/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs:/spark-events
```

Or

```
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs:///spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs:///spark-events
```

Or

```
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://masterIp:9090/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs://masterIp:9090/spark-events
```

should work where `masterIp:9090` is the `fs.default.name` property in `core-site.xml` of `hadoop` configuration.

Apache spark history server can be started by

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

Third party spark history server for example of [Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/admin_spark_history_server.html) can be started by

```
sudo service spark-history-server start
```

And to stop the history server (for Apache)

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/stop-history-server.sh
```

Or (for cloudera)

```
sudo service spark-history-server stop
```